# How to catch back arrow event once I click on it or reset item color in android?

Tags: android, listview

I have the following problem. I only use for my Application a ListView in the MainActivity. To be able to perform multiple Item selection I implemented the following logic for ListView:

```
listview.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode actionMode, int i, long l, boolean b) {
                Cursor cursor = item_repository.getItemList();
                if (listview.getCheckedItemCount() > 0)
                    actionMode.setSubtitle(listview.getCheckedItemCount() + " item(s) selected");
                cursor.moveToPosition(i);
                if (b) {
                    item_ids.add(cursor.getString(0));
                    listview.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.selected_item_color));
                } else {
                    item_ids.remove(cursor.getString(0));
                    listview.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
            }

            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
                MenuInflater inflater = actionMode.getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.sel_del_btn, menu);
                actionMode.setTitle("Select Item(s)");
                return true;
            }

            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.delete_ab_btn) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder del_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    View del_view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.del_layout, null);
                    del_builder.setView(del_view);
                    AlertDialog del_dialog = del_builder.create();
                    del_dialog.show();

                    Button yes_btn = del_view.findViewById(R.id.yes_btn);
                    yes_btn.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
                        for (String id : item_ids)
                            list_repository.deleteData(id);

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Selected item(s) successfully deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        del_dialog.dismiss();
                        update();
                    });

                    Button no_btn = del_view.findViewById(R.id.no_btn);
                    no_btn.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
                        del_dialog.dismiss();
                    });
                }

                if(menuItem.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
                    // How to catch
                }
                update();
                actionMode.finish();
                return true;
            }

            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
            }
        });
```

The logic works. However, when I select Items an the just cancel selection clicking on back arrow or wherever on the screen, The items stay selected instead of to be dis-selected.

[While item selecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UGR4.jpg)

[while dis-selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHmH2.jpg)

As you can see in the code, I set a different color for selected items manually. Because, this was the most suitable logic for my implementation known me.

I tried to catch an event once back arrow was clicked to reset color manually again, but it does not work, especially I cannot catch its event while cancelling the selection.

How can I solve it?
Many thanks in advance and if I was not enough clear, please let me know, I will try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back arrow Event can be accessed by making use of `onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode)`,

ie

```
 public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked Back Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Hope it may help you.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, it does not work. Is there any other methods? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: No, even the Toast message does not pop up.

Comment: https : //paste. ofcode. org/ NW7ySHag6M4Q3gzuSNg7T
Please remove spaces and then open the link.
Let me know, if it should not work.

Comment: looked up your code, in onBackPressed() method, please change the this.onBackPressed() to super.OnBackPressed()

Comment: Sure, I had there 'super.' and when it did not work, I just changed it to 'this.' just for test. So, I still cannot get event. I hope you understand which back arrow I mean. This is that one that during item selection on the action/tool bar appears.

Comment: Ok that backArrow is an Image or menu ??

Comment: I think this is a standard arrow button and the Toolbar is also standard, because I did not add it from myself. I only added the delete button which appears together with back arrow on the toolbar while item selecting.

Comment: Code is updated, please have a look and update your code like wise and let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm very sorry bro. It still does not work. I cannot get an event from back arrow (Toolabar/Actionbar).

Comment: I would like to clarify once again. I need to get an event once I click on arrow on the toolbar, I do not mean the arrow on the bottom of screen. Thank you very much that you try to help me to solve this problem.

Comment: can u share the xml  of that class.?

Comment: do you mean XML of main class?

Comment: Here my friend: https: //paste.ofcode.org/ 368g3KqWdbBfnSbPKLyGAPV

Comment: this is having a listview and floating action button, which one is having toolbar??

Comment: no one is having toolbar. I did not implement it. The toolbar is default one. I just added there delete button which is visible once an item at least is selected.

Comment: Mark, if you are not having any issues, share your project as zip to sachinvarmaraja@gmail.com, will do the needful and return it to you.

Comment: ok, I will zip the project and send you soon. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I receive an error according to your mail box. sachinvarmaraja@gmail.com does not work. Could you please give me a right me. Thank you.